# Difference between append and insert mode in Vim

Tags: vim

I noticed this accidentally when playing around in vimtutor. What's the difference between append and insert mode in Vim? When I type `a` in normal mode (not `A`) I can insert text. When should I use one and not the other?

Comment: In addition to [m0j0Priest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6486600/m0j0priest)'s post, a $ sign also moves to end of the line but without going to INSERT mode

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The append command will put the cursor *after* the current position, while the insert command will put the cursor *before* it.

Using the append command  is like moving the cursor one character to the right, and using the insert command.

Using the insert command  is like moving the cursor one character to the left, and using the append command.

You choose which depending on where you want to start typing.

Comment: Does the cursor really move left? I think of it more as just staying put. The status line shows that too. It certainly moves left once you go back to normal mode though.

Comment: Consider that the cursor is *on* a character in the text.  Insert makes the insertion point go to the left, append goes to the right of that character.

Comment: The difference is clearer in gVim, where the insert mode cursor is a vertical bar between characters like in other GUI editors, but the command mode cursor is still a full rectangle around an entire character.

Comment: Another point: aside from using the arrow keys in insert mode, you can't use `i` or `I` to add text at the very end of a line, and you can't use `a` or `A` to add text at the beginning of a line. Of course one should never use the arrow keys in Vim, so that's one reason it's important to have both insert and append.

Comment: Is there any advantage to this behavior compared to most other text-mode applications work (f.ex. terminals), where the insertion point is always to the left of the cursor and the cursor can be moved one step beyond the end of the line?

Answer (score 51):

Note that `vimtutor` doesn't initially make the case of the command obvious:

SHIFT+A (capital A, as opposed to a) the cursor moves to the *end* of the current line.

SHIFT+I (capital I, as opposed to i)moves to the start of the *current* line.

Comment: This should be fixed IMO. I just fell for that.

Comment: 5 years later, still an issue

Answer (score -1):

Another important aspect on **Append** is that if the position *after* the current position is a empty space followed by a word. After you are done writing it will concatenate both words.

E.g. A file with the following text:

H*i* there.

With the cursor on *i*. After pressing the *a* button and then *ESC* you would have:

H*i*there.

Comment: You are right. I guess it only happened on an emulator I was using back then.